# Decomposition of singular symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, matrix-decomposition

The following came up as part of another problem I was looking at involving quadratic forms. Given a real symmetric 3x3 matrix $\mathbf{A}$ with $|\mathbf{A}| = 0$, find two vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ such that $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{u}\mathbf{v}^T + \mathbf{v}\mathbf{u}^T$.

Is this always solvable? If so, is there a simple way to represent $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ in terms of $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: Is the base field $\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes. I probably should have specified it is a real matrix.

Comment: u will A to have rank two for this to happen.

Comment: No it can happen with an A of rank 1.

Answer (score 0):

Let A be a diagonal matrix with two of the diagonal entries equal to 1, and the third one equal to 0. For such a matrix A, there do not exist vectors u,v with real coefficients for which the specified relation holds.

Comment: Hmm, true. What are the conditions for such vectors to exist? Do such vectors always exist if they are allowed to be complex (but A is still real)?

Comment: If u,v are allowed to be complex, then yes, I think it will always be possible.